# N smallest elements in original order (performance edition) codewars

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I tried to solve this kata on codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/5aeed69804a92621a7000077 but I've got some difficulties. My solution is:

```
function performantSmallest(arr, n) {
    let tmp = [...arr]
    let arrMin = [...tmp.sort((a, b) => a - b).splice(0,n)], result = [];
    
    arr.map(elem => {
        arrMin.map((el, i) => {
            if(elem === el){
                result.push(elem);
                arrMin.splice(i, 1)
            }
        })
    })

    return result;
}
```

It passed first test https://prnt.sc/106othu but when I pressed "Reset" button I've got the timeout error.
Could somebody explain me please correct solution. Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. You can use `.forEach` or an actual loop.

Comment: A question here on SO has to be complete and don't rely on content from external resources. So please add all relevant information (e.g. the actual requirement) in your question, + a [mcve] with input and the expected output.

Comment: One possibility: set an array of indices `index = (0, 1, 2, 3, ..., size-1)`, sort (stable sort) them (`i`) according of the values `arr[i]|`, extract the first `n` indices, sort these indices according to their own values, and print the `arr[index[i]]`. Sorry, don't know javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that there is a scan of `arrMin` for *every* value in the input array. Also, but less important: `splice` should be avoided unless it is really needed. In the first use, you could have used `slice`, and in that same statement, there is no need to take a copy of the result with the spread syntax.

I had a first attempt to remove these inefficiencies, but the sorting seemed to be the bottleneck for larger arrays. So then I implemented a Max Heap (sadly, JavaScript offers no native heap implementation). This can be used to efficiently find the n<sup>th</sup> smallest value in the input. This value will become the maximum value in the output.

Then, you should *count* the number of times this maximum output value should occur in the output.

Finally, you can scan the original array to collect the output, taking into account that count for the maximum number.

```js
// Max Heap implementation
const MaxHeap = {
    siftDown(arr, i=0, key=arr[i]) {
        if (i >= arr.length) return;
        while (true) {
            let j = i*2+1;
            if (j+1 < arr.length && arr[j] < arr[j+1]) j++; // Get child with GREATEST value
            if (j >= arr.length || key >= arr[j]) break; // 
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            i = j;
        }
        arr[i] = key;
    },
    heapify(arr) {
        for (let i = arr.length>>1; i--; ) this.siftDown(arr, i);
        return arr;
    },
    exchange(arr, value) {
        if (!arr.length) return value;
        let oldValue = arr[0];
        this.siftDown(arr, 0, value);
        return oldValue;
    },
    // Include for completeness sake; but not used:
    push(arr, key) {
        let i = arr.length;
        let j;
        while ((j = (i-1)>>1) >= 0 && key > arr[j]) { // Bubble up when key is GREATER than potential parent
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            i = j;
        }
        arr[i] = key;
        return arr;
    },
    pop(arr) {
        return this.exchange(arr, arr.pop());
    }
};

// Main algorithm
function performantSmallest(arr, n) {
    // Create a max heap of size n
    let heap = MaxHeap.heapify(arr.slice(0, n));
    // Scan the rest of the input and keep the smallest n numbers in the max heap
    for (let i = n; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < heap[0]) MaxHeap.exchange(heap, arr[i]);
    }
    // Count the number of occurrences of the maximum value in the heap
    let max = heap[0];
    let count = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (heap[i] === max) count++;
    }
    // Filter the input for numbers that are in the heap
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < max || arr[i] === max && count-- > 0) result.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

// Demo on some inputs:
console.log(performantSmallest([1,2,3,4,5],3)); // [1,2,3] 
console.log(performantSmallest([5,4,3,2,1],3)); // [3,2,1]
console.log(performantSmallest([1,2,3,4,1],3)); // [1,2,1]
console.log(performantSmallest([2,1,3,2,3],3)); // [2,1,2]
```

### Other solutions

There are some solutions on Code Wars that use a particular property of plain objects in JavaScript: when object properties are non-negative integers up to 2<sup>31</sup>, then these are iterated in numerical order.

So if you make a frequency table for the input in such a plain object, you can easily iterate that object and determine what the n<sup>th</sup> smallest value is in the input, much like the heap-solution offers.

However, this only works when the input only contains values in the range 0..2<sup>31</sup>. Other values would *not* be iterated in numerical order, but in insertion order. Apparently the test suit does not have inputs with negative numbers (a pity), as that would have prevented such solutions from being submitted.